# load data infile fields teminated by '¤'

Tags: php, mysql, csv, currency, sign

I have an file with Currency Sign delimeter :
20130217¤18122¤14
20130217¤62152¤14
20130217¤54512¤10

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$file'
   REPLACE INTO TABLE $my_table
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '¤'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
```

The table has columns date, id, num.

The error is #1292 - Incorect date value: '20130217¤18122¤14' for column 'DATE' at row 1

Comment: Terminating with a Unicode character is really odd. Where did you get this data?

Comment: just replace the thing with a coma, or import the whole line as a string and break it after with substring_index

Comment: I get the file with this format. I choose the load data for import file speed. The substring_index, will decrease the import speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this is because non-ASCII terminators are not fully supported.

See [this error message](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_warn_non_ascii_separator_not_implemented) in the docs:

> Error: 1638 SQLSTATE: HY000 (WARN_NON_ASCII_SEPARATOR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
>    Message: Non-ASCII separator arguments are not fully supported

The good news is that multi-character separators *are* supported, so you could use `sed` or something to replace your `¤` with `#%&%#` or something equally unique, and use that as a separator:

> The FIELDS TERMINATED BY, LINES STARTING BY, and LINES TERMINATED BY values can be more than one character.

(see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html#idm46986324131392))

Comment: Yes. The problem is that non-ASCII characters aren't supported as separators, so the solution is to use a different character (or, as my preference, a unique sequence of characters).